# Где почитать о php на тему создания маски и условий для автозаполнения мета-тегов?

Tags: php

Где почитать о php на тему создания маски и условий для автозаполнения мета-тегов?
Здравствуйте. Я начинающий, хочу изучить тему автоматизации заполнения мета-тегов.

Чтобы лучше понять мой вопрос приведу пример:
Есть сайт. На нем страница «новости» и на ней много превтюшек новостей. Хочу научиться настраивать автоматическое заполнение title и description внутри каждой новости по маске «$news->title (точнее заголовок новости) - название сайта» , чтобы не прописывать все вручную.

Но возникает проблема, в переменную $news ничего не передается, она остается пустая и если на странице /news могу с помощью условия присвоить переменным мета-тегов значения:

```html
<?php 
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/news/') {
  $description = " Содержание description';
  } 
?>
```

То на внутренние статьи не получается.

Сам вопрос: Не понимаю, как это все устроенно. Помогите подсказкой, где изучить такое? Естественно, что в интернете, но даже не могу понять, что вбивать в гугл. На какую тему искать информацию? Изучаю все сам с нуля, шаг за шагом, поэтому прошу не кидайте помидорами.

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что вам именно пых надо изучать? Сдаётся мне, решение неправильное)

Comment: @Dillinger è morto Может я и ошибаюсь. Но додумался только таким способом делать